# Chrome: Javascript-Window.showModal Dialog not supporting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, modal-dialog

Steps to reproduce the problem:
1. To Open a Modal Dialog Window Using Javascript function 'window.showmodalDialog'.
2. It does not works like the nature of window.showmodal Dialog
3. It allow to access the Parent Window.

Expected behavior?
If i Open the Modal Window using Javascript function Window.showmodalDialog(), it should take all the control. it should not allow to access the Parent Window. It works in all other Major Browsers. In Chrome, Not Supporting.

any other way to to supporting the same ???

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

The `window.showModalDialog();` method was originally an [Internet Explorer proprietary method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and was only "adopted" in other browsers for basic compatibility purposes.

From my experience the support is not very complete and thus I would highly advise against using it and stick to the standard `window.open();` method if you need a popup.

**Notes:**

According to the MDN ([Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.showModalDialog?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.showModalDialog)) there is **some** support for this in Firefox and Safari.  They also indicate that there is an effort to standardize this method for HTML5 however the HTML5 version **does not** include the 3rd argument "options").

The WhatWG has a [spec listing the status of this HTML5 feature](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dialogs-implemented-using-separate-documents) which currently (Sept. 9, 2013) indicates that **NO** browser currently properly implements the spec and passes all test cases.

*Similar limitations apply to the "partner" method [window.showModelessDialog();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

Comment: thank you for your response. OK, If i use window.open means user can allow to access the parent window. but i don't want this. any other way . please help me. i'm surfing and spend so many hours on this. hope you give me the good suggestion.

Comment: Currently your best solution is to provide an "overlay" or "lightbox" effect placing your "dialog" content in a `div` that you position absolutely over top of your page content... and block out interaction with the page below with a "mask" layer. E.g. the jQuery .dialog() http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: can you please give me a small explanation about your suggestion in javascript. ?

Comment: this is my calling code for modalwindow, hwo can i modify this, please suggest me,:  window.showModalDialog('/servlet/ZServlet?api=loadJBdDetails&jID=1&dePubFlag=0&dEag=0&rand='+myRandom,obj,"dialogHeight: 600px; dialogWidth: 1100px; dialogTop: px; dialogLeft: px; center: Yes; help: No; resizable: No; status: No; scroll: yes;minimize:no;");

Comment: You need some code that will generate, show & hide the "fake" popup.  If you feel up to the task you can write your own... but since there are several solutions already out there I'd suggest using one of those if you're not sure how to go about building your own. If you do want to roll your own this post might help: http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cwolff/Pure-CSS-Modal-Overlays